# ¿Cómo eliminar datos guardados de una base de datos? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

He estado trabajando en un proyecto que almacena, modifica y elimina datos. Lo he estado desarrollando en *C# Visual Studio*, y mi base de datos en *SQL Server 2014*.

Me he dado a la tarea de investigar cómo crear las conexiones y cómo guardar, modificar y eliminar datos.

Lo que tengo por el momento es la conexión a la base de datos y el botón de guardar datos, y en este momento me he dedicado a crear el botón de Eliminar, pero me marca un error.

Código C#:

```
public class Eliminar
{
    public static int Elimina(Variables.Variable01 va)
    {
        int retorno = 0;
        using (SqlConnection Conn = Conexion.Cone())
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Delete 
            from Usuarios2 where Num = {0}", va),
                    Conn);
            retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Conn.Close();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Que error te entrega?

Comment: Hola que tal, me marca el siguiente error

    Excepción no controlada del tipo 
    'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll

    Información adicional: The multi-part identifier 
    "Lista_alta_de_usuarios_link.Variables" could not be bound.

Y lo marca en esta linea de codigo

    retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Tu código actual no es válido. ¿Seguro tienes al `Delete` y el `from` en líneas diferentes?  ¿Qué valor te devuelve `va.ToString()`?  ¿Hay un triggers definidos en tu tabla `Usuarios2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas de la siguiente manera :

```
try
{
    //using (var sc = Conexion.Cone()) En el caso que tengas encapsulada la apertura y cierre de la base de datos dentro de una funcion
    using (var sc = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
    {
        sc.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Usuario2 WHERE Num = @va";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@va", va);  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Error SQL
}
```

Primero intenta siempre poner las conexiones a base de datos dentro de los bloques `try` y `catch` para poder controlar errores y que no haga que el programa deje de funcionar. Intenta manejar las conexiones de la base de datos donde se creen y se cierren en el momento con el fin de no caer en errores de este tipo. Tambien te recomendé cambiar la manera en que haces la consulta a tu base de datos y ocuparas `CommandText` y `Parameters.AddWithValue` con el fin de que leer el código sea mas fácil, concatenar valores en una consulta suele ser desordenado, más aun cuando contamos con clases, propiedades y metodos que nos ayudan y simplifican el tipeo de codigo.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar mas detalles en cuanto a por qué lo recomiendas, y por qué piensas que esto va a solucionar su problema?

Comment: @sstan actualizado

Comment: tendre en cuenta todo lo comentado, muchas gracias por su ayuda